# How to use OrderBy with GreaterThan Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

I want to add in my Repository interface a method which find all the data greater than a `long publishdata` value and Order it Decreacingly:

I tried this, but it doesn't seems to be working:

```
@Repository
public interface NoticiaRepository extends CrudRepository<Noticia,Long>{

    Noticia findById(long id);
    List<Noticia> findByOrderPublishdateGreaterThanDesc(long publishdate);

}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
List<Noticia> findByPublishdateGreaterThanOrderByPublishdateDesc(Long publishdate)
```

Comment: I used documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation